# How to automatically close a terminal popup window if a python script run in it didn't return any error?

Tags: terminal, terminal-buffer, popup-menu, popup

I am wondering if there is a way to automatically close a popup window running a terminal if the execution of the last program didn't report any error and to keep it open if the execution of the last program returns an error.

For example, if I have a function that a) opens a popup terminal b) run a `python some_script.py` program.

I wish that the popup automatically close if the `python some_script.py` didn't return any error, and it is kept open if the `python some_script.py` returned some error.

How to do that?

EDIT: I edited title and description specializing it for Python scripts (which is what I actually need).

EDIT: Here is an excerpt of my code (Vim9):

```
# List all terminal names
var terms_name = []
for ii in term_list()
    add(terms_name, bufname(ii))
endfor

# Start a new terminal if needed
if term_list() == [] || index(terms_name, 'MYTERM') == -1
    term_start(&shell, {'term_name': 'MYTERM', 'hidden': 1, 'term_finish': 'close'})
    set nowrap
endif

# Add popup
b:myterm_pup_id = popup_create(bufnr('MYTERM'), {
    title: " MyTerm ",
    line: &lines,
    col: &columns,
    pos: "botright",
    posinvert: false,
    close: 'button',
    resize: true
    })

# Send a command to the terminal in the popup
term_sendkeys(bufnr('MYTERM'), "python some_script.py \n")

# The tricky part is here: 
# if `python some_script.py` didn't return any error, then call popup_close(b:myterm_pup_id), otherwise keep the popup opened.
```

Comment: You would use `:help term_start()` and handle errors in callbacks, as per `:help job-options`. `term_start()` would return a buffer number to be used in `:help popup_create()`. In any case, you must show us your code if you want us to help improve it.

Comment: Isn't the desired behavior pretty close to how `:cw` works out of the box? Run `:make` and `:cw` will show or hide Quickfix depending on whether there were errors.

Comment: @Friedrich I realized that in general it may not be possible, so I edited my question to be more specific (i.e. added a python example). Feel free to remove your comment if you wish. :)

Comment: Thank you for improving your question. I'll leave my comment around for now. It may still be possible to utilize Quickfix by providing adequate `makeprg` and `errorformat` options. These would have to be rather specific, to the point of becoming impractical.

Comment: @Friedrich I was thinking about to completely change approach and to use `makeprg` but I have the feeling that writing and adequate `errorformat` would be a nightmare. Let's see if someone come up with some other suggestions :) Maybe one could redirection the terminal output due to the `term_sendkey` command in a scratch buffer and then search for the keywords like `Error` or `Traceback` and if such a keyword is found then keep the popup opened (horrible but it may work for a very tiny number of use-cases). I have no clue how to implement it though.